# How to run an application based on TensorFlow 2 in Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am relatively new to TensorFlow, so I have been trying to run simple applications locally, and everything was going well.
At some point I wanted to Dockerize my application. Building the Docker image went with no errors, however, when I tried to run my application, I received the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'. Did you mean: 'fill'?
```

- After googling about the problem, I understood that it is caused by version differences between TF1 and TF2.
  One of the explanation about the problem I found is found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31315#issuecomment-518260943).
- Locally, I am using TF2 (specifically `2.9.1`), inside a virtual environment.
- When dockerizing, I also confirmed from inside the docker container that my TF version is the same.
- I also tried to run the container in interactive mode, and create virtual environment, and install all dependencies manually, exactly the same way I did locally, but still with no success.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3-slim

# ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
# RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
# ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /objectDetector

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

RUN pip3 install update && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install tensorflow==2.9.1
RUN pip3 install tensorflow-object-detection-api
RUN pip3 install opencv-python
RUN pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

COPY detect_objects.py .
COPY detector.py .
COPY helloWorld.py .

ADD data data /objectDetector/data/
ADD models /objectDetector/models/
```

So my question is: How can I ran an application using TensorFlow 2 from a docker container?
Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for any help or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in tensorflow 2.0 :
`tf.gfile` was replaced by `tf.io.gfile`

Can you try this ?

Have a nice day,

Gabriel